# Define class properties based on generic parameter

Tags: typescript, generics

```
class Component { }
class ShallowWrapper { }

// generic P is a simple object
class TestContainer<T extends Component, P extends object> 
{
    constructor(reactElement: T, selectors: P) {
        // iterate over selectors and define object properties
    }
    initialize(): void { }
    [elem: keyof P]: any 
    // I need to define class properties based on P's keys
    // -- compiler throws --
    // An index signature parameter type cannot be a union type. 
    // Consider using a mapped object type instead.
}

const p = new TestContainer(new Component, { test: 'a' });

const v = p.test // this throws a type error (property does not exist)
```

In the above code, I'm trying to dynamically define object properties based on generic parameter P. However the compiler throws the error

> An index signature parameter type cannot be a union type. Consider
>   using a mapped object type instead.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 2):

The compiler gives you this error because you are trying to mix syntax for indexed signature parameters with syntax for mapped types. Indexed signature parameters may only be of type `string` or `number`.

You could use a factory method to achieve what you want with strong typing:

```
class Component { }

class TestContainer<T extends Component> {
    static create<T extends Component, P extends object>(reactElement: T, selectors: P) {
        return Object.assign(new TestContainer(reactElement), selectors);
    }

    private constructor(reactElement: T) {}
}

const p = TestContainer.create(new Component(), { test: 'a' });

const v = p.test;
```

By the way, I don't know if you made `Component` empty for illustration, but you should never use an empty class for limiting types. Since TypeScript uses a structural type system an empty class is structurally equivalent to `Object`. This means that `T extends Component` is basically useless because it'd be the same as `T extends Object` which in turn would be the same as just `T`. If you try it you'll see that the following is valid:

```
TestContainer.create(42, { test: 'a' })
```

Comment: Thanks this works. I ended up implementing something similar. The component was there just for illustration :)